# PageNotFound - noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringSecWebApp/welcome] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new to Spring securities. I created a hello world application installed on WAS server and hit http://localhost:9080/SpringSecWebApp/welcome from browser but getting below error

I have google a lot and search almost every question regarding the same on Stack Overflow but solution mentioned over there didn't solve the issue. Please help.

**Error:**
PageNotFound  W org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringSecWebApp/welcome] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

**Referred site:** 
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-example/

**Technologies used :**

Spring 3.2.8.RELEASE
Spring Security 3.2.3.RELEASE

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<display-name>SpringSecWebApp</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- Spring MVC -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

    <!-- Loads Spring Security config file -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com" />
     <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
      </property>
      <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
      </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**spring-security.xml**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    </http>
    <authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
        <user name="test" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

**WebLoginController**

```
@Controller
public class WebLoginController {
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/welcome**" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView welcomePage() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Hello World");
        model.addObject("message", "This is welcome page!");
        model.setViewName("hello");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView adminPage() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Hello World");
        model.addObject("message", "This is protected page!");
        model.setViewName("admin");

        return model;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this in mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml : `<context:component-scan base-package="com.*" />`

Comment: I have already tried this also.. But same error.

Comment: http://localhost:9080/SpringSecurityHelloWorld/welcome because i visited that site and downloaded the code . i successfully run it. i didn`t do any modifications. have you done any thing to project context path?

Comment: I am using /welcome only and not /welcome** in address bar.
As I mentioned above 
http://localhost:9080/SpringSecWebApp/welcome

Comment: Ok. I also did the same. Let me try again

Answer (score 1):

should refer the package in which the controllers are written. In other words if your controller is in `com.springwebapp` package then use `<context:component-scan base-package="com.springwebapp" />`

**Edit:** 
based on your comment I am adding more code:
Try this:

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.springwebapp" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>
```

**Edit 2**: again based on your comment I have changed the code.
Please try this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.springwebapp" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>
```

**removed default-servlet-handler

Comment: Earlier I had same configuration. But this didn't work that is why l changed to <context:component-scan base-package="com" />.
BTW I have controller under com.springwebapp and I tried not only <context:component-scan base-package="com.*" /> also <context:component-scan base-package="com.springwebapp.*" />

Comment: Please see my above edit based on your comment.

Comment: Thanks Sandeep.
I tried with the code you suggested but a new exception is coming now

Error: 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause SimpleFileServlet: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /welcome

Comment: ok. Can you remove <mvc:default-servlet-handler /> and check again?